# Trying to add a padding ony my background image, tried with background origin did not work

Tags: css

I've got this CSS snippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/puw3wv1n/3/
Looks like this
[image]

```
 1 = Main background of <html> (not important, not just for info)
 2 = is just a background image about 5x5px with color 
 3(left)  = is images/bg_l.png (shadow has alpha)
 3(right) = is images/bg_r.png (shadow has no alpa, background is white 


.body_wrapper { 
    background-color:transparent !important;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    border: 5px solid transparent !important;
    background-image: url(images/bg_l.png), url(images/bg_r.png), url(images/bg_bg.png) !important; 
    background-position: left, right, top left  !important;
    background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y,repeat    !important;  
    /*background-size: initial,initial,cover !important; */
    background-origin: content-box, content-box, content-box !important;

}
```

I want that "2" left and right actually get transparent but in between the "3"'s should stay. so that the shadow of 3 applies to the `<html>` background (1)

I have tried it with a transparent border, so that I can use background-origin to start the background-image "3" at the border with border-box and the background image "2" should then start in the center (inside the border) with the padding of the border(5px)

But it does not work when I set

```
background-origin: border-box, border-box, content-box !important;
```

Here is a more usefull image:
[image]

The overstanding color should get transparent but the color inside should stay.

*Update:* 
Here is a fiddle I've made for that https://jsfiddle.net/puw3wv1n/3/

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Roy I've added fiddle

Comment: @servus not sure what you want to solve here... confused on reading your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was not so easy but I've found away todo that.

I've added

```
 background-clip: border-box,border-box, padding-box !important;
 background-origin: border-box, border-box, padding-box !important;
```

and got it to work